# Matching width of Caption background with Table width

Tags: tables, color, tcolorbox

I am trying to color a table with a background color and the caption with a different background color. I must use the `tabular` environment, none of the `tabulary`, `tablarx`, `tabu`, `tabular*` will be helpful for my setup. Please have look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=orange!20}
\begin{document}

%===========================================
\section{ Gender Distribution}
%===========================================
\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{yellow!20}{yellow!20}{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\centering
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-3pt}
\captionof{table}{Duration of Use and Gender Distribution}


\begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{1pc}}c>{\hspace{1pc}}c>{\hspace{1pc}}c>   {\hspace{1pc}}c<{\hspace{1pc}}}
\toprule
 & Female & Male & All \\ 
\midrule
1 year- 2 years & 2 (50) & 2 (13.3) & 4 \\ 
2 years - 3 years & 0 (0) & 4 (26.7) & 4 \\ 
3 years + & 1 (25) & 3 (20) & 4 \\ 
6 months- 1 year & 1 (25) & 3 (20) & 4 \\ 
Less than 6 months & 0 (0) & 3 (20) & 3 \\ 
\midrule
Total & 4 & 15 & 19 \\ 
\bottomrule
\footnotesize{Source:Airtel Survey}\end{tabular}
}

}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Above code produces following table:

[image]

I would like to extend the caption background so that the spaced denoted by arrow could be covered by the caption background color. Again, please note that I have to use the `tabular` environment and the table width should cover the full text width.  I would greatly appreciate any help with minimum changes in the current setup.

Comment: Do you mean you're not allowed to use `tabularx`?

Comment: I didn't mean "not allowed", it's just that the latex code generated out of R codes uses `tabular` in my document.

Comment: If you do not have too many tables you might change the environment (e. g. with regular expressions).

Comment: Unfortunately quite a few tables are there and I would like to avoid any post-processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have tagged `tcolorbox` but not using it!. Here is a version using your own code. I have commented the changes made in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=orange!20}
\begin{document}

%===========================================
\section{ Gender Distribution}
%===========================================
\begin{center}
\fboxsep0pt %% <<<--- add this.
\fcolorbox{yellow!20}{yellow!20}{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\fboxsep5pt% %%<<--- add this here for making caption's height large
\centering
%\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10pt}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-3pt}   %% <<<--- this messes up
\captionof{table}{Duration of Use and Gender Distribution}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{1pc}}c>{\hspace{1pc}}c>{\hspace{1pc}}c>   {\hspace{1pc}}c<{\hspace{1pc}}}
\toprule
 & Female & Male & All \\
\midrule
1 year- 2 years & 2 (50) & 2 (13.3) & 4 \\
2 years - 3 years & 0 (0) & 4 (26.7) & 4 \\
3 years + & 1 (25) & 3 (20) & 4 \\
6 months- 1 year & 1 (25) & 3 (20) & 4 \\
Less than 6 months & 0 (0) & 3 (20) & 3 \\
\midrule
Total & 4 & 15 & 19 \\
\bottomrule
\footnotesize{Source:Airtel Survey}\end{tabular}
}%   %<<<<--- % needed here
%   <<<--- don't leave blank line here for better
}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harish. Its almost there, is there any way to increase the width of caption background? It became little narrow for my taste.

Comment: Sorry not the width, I actually meant height of caption background, basically I need to have more top and bottom padding around the caption text.

Comment: @RushadFaridi Please see the edit.

Comment: Ciao Harish!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @karlkoeller Hi Karl! How are you?